# How to calculate the length till a certain word in a sentence

Tags: python, string, string-length

```
str1 = "If you're reading this half sentence you are amazing because it's half."
```

I don't want the length of the entire string.I need the length until it reaches the word **because**.It should give me the length of:-

> "If you're reading this half sentence you are amazing "

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.find).

Example:

```
>>> str1 = "If you reading this half sentence you are amazing because it's half."
>>> print(str1.find('because'))
50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another function str.index(), it does the same thing. The only difference between find() and index() is find() method return -1 if it doesn't find the sub string but index() method raises an exception.
Usage:
   len = str1.index('because')

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it this way, must you include whitespace or not?

```
def find_till_word(sentence, word):
    count = 0
    for char in sentence[:sentence.index(word)]:
        count += 1
    return count
```

Output:

```
>>> str1 = "If you reading this half sentence you are amazing because it's half."
>>> print(find_till_word(str1, "because"))
50
```